# remove duplicates from two string arrays c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How can i effectively remove duplicates from two string arrays? I want to remove all the duplicates from a `string[] a` that are in a separate `string[] b`

for example

```
a = { "1", "2", "3", "4"};
b = { "3", "4", "5", "6"};
```

the result i am looking for would just be

```
c = { "5", "6"};
```

Comment: What happened with "2" and "1"? There are appear once... Should they be in the result?

Comment: @poplitea that duplicate question is different, it only gives the duplicates in 1 array not two different arrays

Comment: @nemesv no array b would be an updated version of a

Comment: +1 I think this is an interesting question and cannot understand why you got so much downvotes

Comment: There might be a conspiracy to get the reversal gold badge... lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) produces set difference of two sequences

```
var c = b.Except(a).ToArray(); // gives you { "5", "6" }
```

Answer (score 14):

```
var final = b.Except(a).ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try using this:-

```
 List<string[]> moves = new List<string[]>();
 string[] newmove = { piece, axis.ToString(), direction.ToString() };
 moves.Add(newmove);
 moves.Add(newmove);

 moves = moves.Distinct().ToList();
```

or try this:-

```
 var c = b.Except(a).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
             Foo(m.Length-1);
        }
        static string m = "1234"; 
        static string c = "3456"; 
        static int ctr = 0;
        static void Foo(int arg)
        {
            if (arg >= 0)
            {
                Foo(arg - 1);
                Console.Write(m[arg].ToString());
                for (int i = ctr; i <  m.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (c[i].ToString() == m[arg].ToString())
                    {
                        ctr++;
                        break;
                    }
                }  
                if(arg==m.Length-1)
                {
                    for (int i = ctr; i <m.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(c[i].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```